# Android kill background application from our application programmatically

Tags: android, kill-process

My requirement forces me to kill another apps from my developed application.

Details:
My requirement is how to kill all background running application from currently developing application programmatically.

I refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829606/android-adb-stop-application-command-like-force-stop-for-non-rooted-device) but I am not able to understand how to implement this. Actually I want to develop somthing like [ShutApp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yirga.shutapp). In this, application force-closes app other background running application.

I am stuck into developing this feature. Any hint/suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

Comment: "running application from our application "? what?

Comment: It means the application which is I am developing right now I want to kill other running apps from that only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do Task Manager's kill apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303615/how-do-task-managers-kill-apps)

Answer (score 3):

**This will force-stop all applications including system-app**

```
    try
     {
        Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());

        os.writeBytes("adb shell" + "\n");
        os.flush();

        Context newContext=this;
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) newContext.getSystemService( Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
        List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for(RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses){
            if(appProcess.processName.equals("com.yourPackageName")){
             }
             else{
                os.writeBytes("am force-stop "+appProcess.processName + "\n");
             }
          }

        os.flush();
        os.close();
        suProcess.waitFor();

     }

     catch (IOException ex)
     {
         ex.getMessage();
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
     catch (SecurityException ex)
     {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't get root access2",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't get root access3",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is not possible, it would be bad practice for Android to allow apps to close other apps.

The answer is in this post: [Kill another process/application programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563404/kill-another-process-application-programmatically)

Please google your question before asking it here.

Comment: I know this would be bad practice but I have requirement for the same. And also all battery saver application is following same procedure. I just want to know how can we develop this.

Comment: See my edit, please use google to find your answers before you ask it here.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but I already tried this and its not working. Please be sure before suggesting the answer  :)

Comment: Did you add the permission to the Manifest?

Comment: Yes I added all required permissions.

Comment: See my edited question. I added all those permission into my Manifest.xml. Here I dont want to kill my current working app. But through my current app I want to kill all other background running apps.

Comment: The answer referred here doesn't work! I hope the author must have tried this before referring it.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot actually kill all the background apps . However, we can kill our own app from recents by calling [finishAndRemoveTask()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.AppTask.html#finishAndRemoveTask()) which is available from lollipop.

Another Solution is we can use `android:excludeFromRecents` in activity in the manifest file